# Stripe API YTD Payouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a Dashboard, and one of the items I'd like to list is the Gross Volume for YTD from the Stripe API.

Can anyone help me out? I'm working in Rails, I've got a successful call to the API and I can get returns, but I can't figure out how to add all of the payouts->amounts together to give me YTD information.

```
@payoutList = Stripe::Payout.list.to_json
```

is what I've got so far.

[API Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#list_payouts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@payoutList["data"].sum { |payout| payout["amount"] }
```

If you want to sum all payouts YTD and you have a large number of them, I would do it like this:

```
sum = 0
last_payout_id = nil
start_at = Time.now.beginning_of_year.to_i
end_at = Time.now.end_of_year.to_i

loop do
  payouts = Stripe::Payout.list(limit: 100, status: "paid", created: { gte: start_at, lte: end_at }, starting_after: last_payout_id)
  break if payouts.data.empty?

  sum += payouts.data.sum { |payout| payout.amount }
  last_payout_id = payouts.data.last.id
end
```

There are probably ways to refactor the above, but here are the important points I see:

- Provide the created param to ensure you only get payouts of the current year.
- I'm guessing you only want to get payouts which have been paid (it's possible you'd get pending, failed, or canceled payouts without this).
- Since the payouts API method returns a maximum of 100, you'll have to continue to get a list of payouts until the list is empty.

I'd also try looking for a way to retrieve the total payouts amount directly from Stripe's API. I'm not sure it exists though. That way, you're not the one who has to do the math.

Comment: I've got 117 payouts at this time, I expect double that by end of next year. I think it only gave me my first payout which was 409.5. The output I got from that is 410. Should be about 6129. hmm Could you break that down?

Comment: I edited my answer with more information. Since you have 117 payouts, you'll need to make 3 calls to `Stripe::Payout.list`. The last call should return an empty array of data and break the loop. I also added the other params you should specify to make sure you're only getting YTD payouts.

Comment: I'd put that in my controller right? New to the MVC way of doing things and Rails for that matter. Sadly the api doesn't exist to pull the net total. I can get it if I export direct from stripe, but I'd rather it be pulled upon page reload.

Comment: If you have a model that makes sense, I would put it there. That way, you could just do this in your controller: `@model.ytd_payouts`. It's useful to put it in your model so you can easily reuse it elsewhere. Otherwise, you may find yourself needing to copy/paste the logic in a number of places.

Comment: figured it out. I put the code in my controller, and change the sum variable to @sum. Now do do the decimal point. or round it. Thanks Derek.